# request.getParameter returns null in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm making an ajax call using jquery.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/test",
    data: {"mykey":"test value"},
    success: function(appSubFtrResult){
        /**/
    },
    error: function(){
        /**/
    }
});
```

In servlet/filter i'm unable to get the values using `request.getparameter("mykey");` which is returning null. Instead, if I use `request.getParameterNames()` and iterate like below, i'm able to get all the data and its value.

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("mykey")); // returns null
Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames();
while(params.hasMoreElements()){
    String name = params.nextElement();
    String value = request.getParameter(name);

    System.out.println("::Request Params:: " + name + " = " + value);   //prints ::Request Params:: mykey = test value
}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem might be here:

```
data: {"mykey":"test value"},
```

You don't need to put the parameter name in quotes:

```
data: {mykey:"test value"},
```

Then in your servlet try:

```
String key = request.getParameter("mykey");
```

Also worth mentioning you can do your ajax like this with jquery (less lines):

```
var params = {mykey: "test value"};
$.post("/test", $.param(params), function(response) {
    // handle response here if you have one
});
```

**EDIT:**

I just tested your code and was able to get the parameter without a problem (in chrome). So quotes around the parameter name shouldn't make a difference. So try doing your ajax differently like in my example, see if that helps.